# How to load a 32-bit RGB string with a given width and height into a Pixmap in Xlib?

Tags: string, rgb, xlib, pixmap

I want to load an `int` string, which consists of `width` × `height` elements, which represents a 32-bit RGB value into a `Pixmap` in Xlib.

I've just found `XReadBitmapFile()`, which can read from a X Bitmap to X Pixmap, and this might not really meets my needs.

So, should I design a new function to process it? Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Read up on XImage and associated functions, google for examples.

Answer (score -1):

```
void drawString::DrawString(Display *d, Drawable win, XFontStruct *fontType, int rectWidth, int rectHeight, int HAlign, int VAlign, char* fmt, unsigned long color, unsigned long textColor, Pixmap bgPixmap)
{
    GC gc;

    if( initValues->blnExitUITThread )
        return;

    if( fontType == NULL )
        return;

    unsigned short fontHeight, fontWidth, singleFontHeight;
    int x, y;
    Pixmap pixmap;
    char* token;

    initValues->trueColor = textColor;

    pixmap = XCreatePixmap(d, win, rectWidth, rectHeight, DefaultDepth(d, 0));
    gc = XCreateGC(d, pixmap, 0, NULL);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?